# Fitting parameter to match a dataset to another dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, fitting, data

I am using a Module which calculates 3D-data based on 5 parameters and another input dataset.
I'd like to fit the result of this modul to another set of data.

Since my code became very long I will break down the idea to a schematic code shown below:

```
data0 = {{0, 0, 5}, {0, 1, 7}, {1, 0, 9}, {1, 1, 3}}
CalculateData[data_, p0_,p1_] := Module[{data1},
  data1 = calculationBasedOnTheseParameters[data[[i]][[3]]*p1+p0]; 
  Return data1
  ]
data2 = {{0, 0, 10}, {0, 1, 14}, {1, 0, 18}, {1, 1, 6}};
SomeFitFunction[data2, CalculateData[data0, p1,p0], {{p0, 0.1},{p1,2.1}}]
```

My Problem is that the calculation is based on Interpolation of data0 based on 5 parameters which is the reason why I can't use the LestSquares Function. I did not find a fit function which reduces the LeastSquares of two datasets for a given set of parameters. Of course it might also be possible to extract the values from the data to list. The a function might just compare the average meansquare of every value based on the input parameters; such as

```
list2 = Table[data2[[i]][3]],{i,1,4}]
(*and the modified function from above:*)
CalculateList[data_, p0_,p1_] := Module[{list1},
  list1 = calculationBasedOnTheseParameters[data[[i]][[3]]*p1+p0]; 
  Return list1
  ]
SomeOtherFitFunction[list2, CalculateList[data0, p1,p0], {{p0, 0.1},{p1,2.1}}]
```

So do you know a function which works as the wished "Some(Other)FitFunction" in this case?

kind regards
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

We can use `FindMinimum` to compute parameters, for example

```
data0 = {{0, 0, 5}, {0, 1, 7}, {1, 0, 9}, {1, 1, 3}}
CalculateData[data_, p0_, p1_] := 
 Module[{data1}, dim = Dimensions[data]; 
  data1 = Table[
    If[j == 3, data[[i, j]]*p1 + p0, data[[i, j]]], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j,
      dim[[2]]}];
  data1]
data2 = {{0, 0, 10}, {0, 1, 14}, {1, 0, 18}, {1, 1, 6}};

FindMinimum[
 Norm[Mean[data2 - CalculateData[data0, p1, p0]]]^2, {{p0, 1/10}, {p1,
    21/10}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 10]

Out[]= {1.24738996976747894159133814019*10^-29, {p0 -> 
   1.60810810810810751621742076809, 
  p1 -> 2.35135135135135137085463842344}}
```